What is a patch document?
I am trying to learn how to use patch method to partially update a table in a database. In RFC 5789, it is mentioned that:

The PATCH method requests that a set of changes described in the
request entity be applied to the resource identified by the
Request-URI. The set of changes is represented in a format called a
"patch document" identified by a media type.

Is application/json considered a patch document? I am aware of RFC 7396 and RFC 6902, but both say that:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7396

A JSON merge patch document describes changes to be made to a target JSON document

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902

JSON Patch defines a JSON document structure for expressing a sequence of operations to apply to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) document

I am not making changes to a JSON document, but a database table. So is it OK to use just application/json and not application/merge-patch+json or application/json-patch+json?

It's deliberately not specified. Both of your examples (JSON Merge Patch and JSON Patch) are syntactically JSON with additional semantics, hence application/...+json. Could your server accept just application/json (and validate it against one or the other, or introspect to see which, or assume/validate a different JSON patch format entirely) - yes. Whether the underlying entity is stored in a DB or something else really ought to be irrelevant from the API perspective - the client says "update this entity like this" and the server says (happy path case) "OK here's the updated entity".
